# How can I SELECT additional columns with a TSQL query using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a view (that is a union of several tables) and I need to filter out duplicates. The table looks like this:

```
id    first    last    logo      email    entered
1     joe      smith   i.jpg     e@m.c    2014-01-27
2     jim      smith   b.jpg     e@j.c    2014-01-27
3     bob      smith   z.jpg     b@b.c    2014-01-27
9     joeseph  smith   q.gif     e@m.c    2014-01-20
```

I want to do something like this, but I can't seem to get a valid syntax for it:

```
SELECT 
    email, MAX(entered), first, last -- such that first and last come from the same row as the MAX(entered)
FROM
    my_view
GROUP BY
    email
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT email, entered, first, last
FROM (select v.*, row_number() over (partition by email order by entered desc) as seqnum
      from my_view v
     ) v
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

`row_number()` is a window function that assigns sequential numbers to groups of rows.  The groups are defined by the `partition by` clause.  In this case, everything with the same `email` is in the same group.  The first row is given a value 1; the ordering is based on the `order by` clause.

The outer query select the first one, which has the largest `entered` date.

Comment: Thank you. I accepted your answer, as it explains the reason and the why in more detail.

Answer (score 4):

Since your names are not the same on the duplicate email rows, you must use the [`row_number()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)  function instead:

```
select email, entered, first, last
from (
 select *, row_number() over (partition by email order by entered desc) rn
 from my_view
) x
where rn = 1
```

You need a subquery because `row_number()` is not allowed in the `where` clause.

Comment: The problem, is that doesn't remove the duplicate emails from the result set. This gives me the same results as without the GROUP BY.

Comment: Your sample data has the same name against the duplicate emails - is that not the case in your real data?\

Comment: good point. In my sample here, the names are the same, in my real data, some columns will be the same, but some will not. I'll update my sample.

Comment: Added another solution that should work with non-duplicate names.